# JavaScript: One can't view a non-global variable in the Browser Tool Console?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, console.log

Might be a silly question but it still got me a bit stuck, not being 100% sure of the answers.

So I have an index.html file which calls a function in an example.js-file (just adding it for clarification):

```
function sinusGraph() {
var plotstart = 0, 
    plotrange = 20,
    stepsize = 0.5; // not in use right now

var yValues, xValues;

function sinusValues(startinput, stopinput) 
{ 
    return d3.range(startinput, stopinput+1).map(function(i) 
    {
        return Math.sin(i);
    })
};

function xAxisValues(startinput, stopinput) 
{ 
    return d3.range(startinput, stopinput+1).map(function(i) 
    {
        return i;
    })
};

xValues = xAxisValues(plotstart, plotrange); 
yValues = sinusValues(plotstart, plotrange);  };
```

Writing, for example, "xValues" with the variables declared in the browser's returns "xValues is not defined(...)".

Removing "var xValues" letting it be a global variable does return the value.

My questions:

1. The browser's Tool Console can't see non-global variables within functions?
2. If that is the case, then is this a good tool to look for potential global variables that you have created by mistake?
3. Is there any way to view these variables in the browser's tool console, other than using console.log(myVariable) within the function where it is declared?

Comment: set a break point and inspect the variable when it gets hit, add a console.log line in the code and write the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The browser's Tool Console can't see non-global variables within functions?

Yes.

Here is why it can't work: Local variables of a function only exist while the function is running. Code you type into the console will either be executed before or after the function is executed.
Even if you were able to access local variables after a function was executed:

- which value would you expect to get when you type `varname` in the console? The inital value, the last value or all values?
- what if multiple functions have a local variable with the same name?
- what if the same function was already executed multiple times?

You can only inspect the *current state* of your application.

> If that is the case, then is this a good tool to look for potential global variables that you have created by mistake?

No. You should use a linter such as [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) that warns you if you forget e.g. a `var` declaration. Also enable [*strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode): Assignments to undeclared variables will throw an error then.

> Is there any way to view these variables in the browser's tool console, other than using console.log(myVariable) within the function where it is declared?

[Set a break point](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints) in your code, either through the devtools or via `debugger`. Code execution will pause at the breakpoint and the console has access to everything that is accessible at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The console has to run the code *some* scope (and it can't access a scope defined by a function that isn't running anyway).

Set a breakpoint inside the function, to pause execution there. When that breakpoint is triggered, the console's scope will be to that function.